# Reverse back Postgres field type when migrations were applied in Django

Tags: python, django

I pulled the new code from GitHub and my colleagues changed the type of a field in a `Django` model from `TextField` to `JSONField`. After running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` the type of the field was changed in the database (I suppose). I needed to reverse back to previous migration and somehow the type of the field *was not reversed*. How could I fix the issue? Why reversing back migration does not revert back the field type?

Comment: Did you update the field on the model to be a TextField as well?

Answer (score 1):

Change the field type back to a TextField, then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again. If the migration still exists in your django project, it will look at its `dependencies`, which most likely still links to the migration that turned it into a JSONField. So simply doing the exact same thing to turn it back into a TextField should work